# Embedded XBAP in IFrame always on top

Tags: c#, xaml, iframe, asp.net, xbap

It is possible to embed an XBAP application into an IFrame, this is rather easy !!

The problem however is that it renders on top of anything within the web application. For example!

I have a menu  in my web application which can collapse when I hover above it, but it will collapse UNDER the IFrame when it needs to collapse ON TOP of the IFrame with the XBAP Application in it.

I tried messing with the z-index but this does not fix anything!

It seems it has nothing to do with the IFrame, because when I put plain HTML into the IFrame it renders on top of the IFrame.

My last effort would be to put the XBAP Application in new browser window !! But it would be so much nicer to have it embedded within the application.

[This guy seems to have the same problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/5e01c4b7-df42-46fd-b20b-fd772402e9e3)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with controls/plugins that aren't rendered by the browser itself (these controls have their own windows, which are merely positioned inside the browser instead of composed within it). If you're willing to use Silverlight instead, there is a partial solution available with [windowless controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838156(VS.95).aspx) that will allow you to intermix DOM content and managed code, but they have their own limitations. The upcoming Silverlight 4 can do even more than XBAPs as far as local trust/resource access...